# expand / toggle div with display none from foreach with $ id

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, toggle

I have this:

```
@foreach($portfolios as $portfolio)

<div id="item-portfolio-expand{{$portfolio->id}}" class="item-portfolio-expand expand">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        col-md-8
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        {{ __('Name')}}: {{ $portfolio->name }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

And this:

```
@foreach ($portfolios as $portfolio)  
 <div class="portfolio-item {{ $portfolio->tag }} " data-category="transition">
   <img src="{{ $portfolio->image_show }}">
     <a href="#item-portfolio-expand{{$portfolio->id}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#item-portfolio-expand{{$portfolio->id}}" data-parent="#item-portfolio-expand{{$portfolio->id}}">
       <div class="portfolio-item-overlay">
         <p class="name-item-overlay">{{ $portfolio->name }}</p>
       </div>
     </a>
 </div>
@endforeach
```

And when I press the  in the first `foreach`, I want to toggle the second foreach at `<div id = "item-portfolio-expand {{$ portfolio-> id}}" class = "item- portfolio-expand expand ">` I just don't succeed at anything, I use bootstrap and jquery in the project. `.item-portfolio-expand` has `display: none;`

And at the same time when one is open and another is selected, to close the one already open and to appear the one selected with toggle.

Comment: Are you trying to use bootstrap accordian (collapse/expand) widget ? 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/

Comment: That's what I tried, I just saw that if I take the show display block class, it shows me the selected div, only it doesn't close the other one for me.

Comment: What you want to show in panel header, i mean in clickable area

Comment: I don't know how to explain, when I press the <a> in the first foreach to show me item-portfolio-expand {{$ portfolio-> id}} and if there is any more item-portfolio-expand {{$ portfolio-> id}} open, close it ..

Comment: Which @foreach section is showing expanded row. First or second one

Comment: Remove data-parent="#item-portfolio-expand{{$portfolio->id}}" attribute from <a> tag

Comment: I edited the post, the first foreach displays the expand

Comment: Please follow https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/ syntax

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading it now ..